# What to do for Questions Marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question [How windows detects internet connection?](https://superuser.com/questions/807020/how-windows-detects-internet-connection)
and it was marked duplicate of [How does Windows know whether it has internet access or if a Wi-Fi connection requires in-browser authentication?](https://superuser.com/questions/277923/how-does-windows-know-whether-it-has-internet-access-or-if-a-wi-fi-connection-re)

I visited the question and found useful. What should I do next or How can I accept answer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Marking as accepted is reserved only for those who asked the question. since your question is marked as a duplicate, the appropriate way would be to upvote the answer(s) you found useful.

Comment: .. and perhaps the question since it's obviously a good dupe-catcher.